# Loop through row per rows

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I display an access report that is based on this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Plan_charge.Num_utilisateur, RecupProjet(Num_utilisateur) AS LesProjets
FROM Plan_charge;
```

The function "RecupProjet" in VBA is :

```
Public Function RecupProjet(Num_utilisateur As String) As String

Dim res As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
'Selectionne les participant du projet
SQL = "SELECT Num_EB_Tache FROM Plan_charge WHERE Num_utilisateur=" & _
          Chr(34) & Num_utilisateur & Chr(34)
Set res = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
'Concatene les différents enregistrement
While Not res.EOF
RecupProjet = RecupProjet & res.Fields(0).Value & " "
res.MoveNext
Wend
'Enleve le dernier espace
RecupProjet = Left(RecupProjet, Len(RecupProjet) - 1)
'libere la mémoire
Set res = Nothing

End Function
```

Here is a sample report that I displayed following the code:

[image: Image here]

Now I'd like to go line by line data in this report and make the total of a column ( `Total_charge` of my table `Plan_charge`) according to the column `Num_utilisateur` (for example in SQL : `WHERE Num_utilisateur = Me.Num_utilisateur.Value`) and put the total in a text box called `ChargeTotale`.

Have you got any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Plan_charge.Num_utilisateur,
 RecupProjet(Plan_charge.Num_utilisateur) AS LesProjets, T.ChargeTotale
FROM Plan_charge INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Num_utilisateur, SUM(Total_charge) AS ChargeTotale
 FROM Plan_charge 
 GROUP BY Num_utilisateur) T 
ON Plan_charge.Num_utilisateur = T.Num_utilisateur
```

If you don't need any additional fields from Plan_charge you could just do:

```
SELECT Num_utilisateur, RecupProjet(Num_utilisateur) AS LesProjets,
 SUM(Total_charge) AS ChargeTotale
FROM Plan_charge 
GROUP BY Num_utilisateur, RecupProjet(Num_utilisateur)
```

Comment: Thanks for the second request ! But for the first, I have an error : the specified field "Num_utilisateur" may refer to several tables listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: Great, it works :) Last question for you : to add an additional field in my request, How do you do ?

Comment: If you need non-summary fields specific to the Plan_charge table (like a date field for example) you would use Plan_charge.NameOfField in the first query.

For summary fields you would use the second query and place the field in both the select area and group by.  Really as long as you use the DISTINCT keyword in the top query they work the same.